Account.SalesforceCustomer field missing
Getting an error: "Account.SalesforceCustomer Custom Field -Could not resolve standard field's name." when deploying to scratch org
What feature should be enabled for this field to appear on Account object?
Found one similar topic Account.SalesforceCustomer Could not resolve standard field's name. -Error but no answers
Scratch configuration:
"features": [
    "LiveAgent",
    "PersonAccounts",
    "Knowledge",
    "SurveyAdvancedFeatures",
    "MultiCurrency",
    "EntityTranslation"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "sharingSettings": {
      "enableAssetSharing": true
    },
    "territory2Settings": {
      "enableTerritoryManagement2": true
    },
    "surveySettings": {
      "enableSurvey": true
    },
    "knowledgeSettings": {
      "enableKnowledge": true,
      "defaultLanguage": "en_US",
      "enableLightningKnowledge": true
    },
    "liveAgentSettings": {
      "enableLiveAgent": true
    },
    "workDotComSettings": {
      "enableProfileSkills": true
    },
    "currencySettings": {
      "enableMultiCurrency": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
      "enableQuote": true,
      "enableQuotesWithoutOppEnabled": true
    },
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableTranslationWorkbench": true,
      "enableEndUserLanguages": true
    },
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  }


Unfortunately no, it just specifies to track feed history and that is it


SalesforceCustomer
false

it also used in layouts and reports so deployment of those fails

Can you enable connection finder (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.partner_survey_about.htm&type=5) and deploy

Enabled the connection finder and it worked, thank you @Vinay

Could you please post so I could mark it as an answer?

Np and good to know it worked

As mentioned in comments,  Enabling Connection Finder in an org and try to re-deployment should fix the issue.
